# Home Page Full Width No Side Bar

Tags: php, wordpress, sidebar

I am experimenting with a new design for my front page - http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/front-page-test/

I have set it so Google does not Index this page.

I set the template to Full Width, No Sidebar, this resulted in the plugins being hid but the text and pictures still do not cover the whole page. How can I address this?

This is my code for fullwidth-page.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Full Width, No Sidebar
 *
 * @package Penscratch
 */

// Access global variable directly to set content_width
if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) && isset( $GLOBALS['content_width'] ) )
    $GLOBALS['content_width'] = 1091;

get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">

        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">



            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>


<?php // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template 
if ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() ) : comments_template(); 
endif; ?>

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Impossible to answer without your CSS.  And links to a live site are a no-no, because as soon as the site is [fixed|down|changed|updated|removed] this question has zero value to a future visitor.

Comment: You CAN see his CSS.... He gave a link to his website...

Comment: @kevinniel Questions about existing code need to show a [mcve] of that code _in the question itself_. Links to critical information are not sufficient. The external site may change or go down completely.

Answer (score -1):

To make it easier for you, you can change this line :

`<div id="primary" class="content-area">`

to this line :

`<div id="primary" class="content-area" style="width: 100%;">`

Comment: Are you referring to the Additional CSS?

Comment: I've edited the answer to give you something easy to do